# cannot sign into superuser account/website

Tags: email, passwords

I posted a question and superuser then asked me to set up an account with my email and a password.  But now you won't let me sign in. You say you can't verify my email address?
When I try to sign in you just send me a message to reset  my password. Then when I try to do that you just keep saying you can't verify my email address. What gives??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please start by reviewing the Help center at https://superuser.com/help, and if you continue to have issues, please post your question to Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions